# Node.js Module in Typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

What must the module code (writen in typescript) look like to be able to use it like this:

```
/// <reference path="./onoff.ts" />

//import * as onoff from "./onoff";
var onoff = require("./onoff");

var app = onoff();

var computers: Onoff.Computer[] = [];
app.start(computers);
```

I was sure it must be this, but it does not work:

```
import * as express from "express";
export module Onoff {    

    export class Computer {

    }

    export class OnoffApp {


        start(computers:Computer[], port:number = 3489) {
           ...
        }
    }

    export default function() {
        return new OnoffApp();
    }
}
```

Typescript complains:

```
service/example.ts(5,11): error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature.
service/example.ts(7,16): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'Onoff'.
service/example.ts(8,21): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'Onoff'.
typings/express/express.d.ts(14,1): error TS6053: File 'typings/serve-static/serve-static.d.ts' not found.
typings/express/express.d.ts(28,34): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'serve-static'.
```

thank you very much! I have no Idea what I've done wrong...

Answer (score 1):

1. Judging from the error description, moving the `import` outside of your module should fix your problem:

   ```
   import * as express from "express";
   export module Onoff {
       ...
   }
   ```
2. You import your module as `onoff` but are trying to use `Onoff`

   ```
   var onoff = require("./onoff");
       ^
   var computers: Onoff.Computer[] = [];
                  ^
   ```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the error in onoff.ts but not the other errors. I modified the question accordingly.

Comment: you import your module as `onoff` but are trying to use `Onoff`

Comment: If i do that it says `error TS2305: Module '"service/onoff"' has no exported member 'Computer'..`

Comment: `export default function() {
        return new OnoffApp();
    }`
`var onoff = require(...);`
`onoff` does not have a member Computer, does it?

So if your main module is written in ES6, you can do `import Computer from "./onoff". Alternatively, export an element that also exports `Computer`.